# Checking for when a checkbox turns

Tags: jquery

I need to run a function **when** a checkbox changes from unchecked to checked.

So I use the `.change` event to trigger everything, but check using `.prop` before running the function to make sure that the checkbox is actually checked or unchecked, right?

```
<form>
  <input class="target" type="checkbox" value="Field 1">
</form>

$(".target").change( function(){
    if(this.prop("checked", true)){
        alert("this is checked");
    } else {
        alert("this is not checked");
    }
});
```

The code above doesn't work and I'm not sure why...

I selected the `.target` and it is invoking the `.change` event listener.

`.target` is `this` because it is calling the `.change` method.

So the function is saying "when `.target` changes, check to see if the property "checked" of `.target` is true. If it is, alert. Else, alert something else."

In the jQuery documentation for `.change` it says "The change event is sent to an element when its **value** changes." The **value** that they talk about is **not** the `.val` of the element, right? Totally different "value". Because `.val` of `.target` never, ever changes since it's hard-coded at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is ussing `$(this).is(":checked")` to handle if or else like:

```
$(".target").change( function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        alert("this is checked");
    } else {
        alert("this is not checked");
    }
});
```

Becouse you need to check if it is checked, no set the value to checked. And `this` does not have `.prop()` you need use the Jquery Object `$(this)`.

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7vyTf/)

**EDIT**

I was some wrong about the perfomance about `.is()` vs `.prop()` after test it `.prop()` is much faster than `.is()`.

Both will give us the same result but `.is()` is slower.

```
$(".target").change( function(){
        if($(this).prop(":checked")){
            alert("this is checked");
        } else {
            alert("this is not checked");
        }
    });
```

Or Much faster:

```
$(".target").change( function(){
            if(this.checked){
                alert("this is checked");
            } else {
                alert("this is not checked");
            }
        });
```

[Test performance .is() vs .prop()](http://jsperf.com/prop-vs-ischecked2)

Comment: Are there downsides to using `.prop("checked" === true)` compared to using `.is(":checked")`? On a side note, what does `:` do in this context? I know that `:` is used for a specific jQuery **selector** and is basically a jQuery Extension ie. something defined by jQuery itself. But `:checked` isn't a selector and it's not selecting anything, so what does the colon mean?

Comment: I can't seem to find documentation on pseudo-selector pros and cons? http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: Oh yeah, and I think using `.prop` requires jQuery to search through all the properties of the DOM **object** that you selected. It needs to wait for the DOM object to be created by the browser and then it needs to search the DOM object for the property of `checked` and return whether or not it found it. Sound about right?

Comment: Yes you are right, with .is() is ussing to filter directly if is checked or not, it don't care any other prop or attr. Any way I use .prop to set or know some prop, no to check whether is selected or checked.

Comment: If you want, that how I posted _"Both will give us the same result but .is() is slower"_ only I put the test to clarify about perfomance.

Comment: BTW, this is the correct test - you need to do `.prop("checked" === true)`  - http://jsperf.com/prop-vs-ischecked2/2

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're trying to invoke the method `prop` on an element(which doesn't exist because it's not a jQuery object). You need it check the value, not set it. Change `this.prop("checked", true)` to `$(this).is(':checked')`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the setter version of `prop`, aka you are telling the checkbox to be `checked`. You should be using the getter version of `prop`.

```
if($(this).prop('checked') === true){
    alert("this is checked");
} else {
    alert("this is not checked");
}
```

**Edit:** my bad, late here and just sure the incorrect use of prop. Updated the this reference.

or

```
if(this.checked === true) { ...
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Probably because `this` is used incorrectly.

Comment: Doing this works: `if($(this).prop("checked" === true))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/kb3xa/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".target").click(function () {
     if ($(".target").is(":checked")) {
         alert("this is checked");
        }
         else{
          alert("this is not checked");
        }
     });
});
```